# Why does python allow 'some' keywords to be assigned a value?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, keyword

Python3 allows some keywords to be assigned values (Which is bad according to my professor...)

For example:

```py
>>> int = 10
>>> print(int)
10
>>> #But...
>>> print = 20
>>> print(print)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

But in C++:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    int int=0; //yeah, this is absurd...
    printf("%d",int);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```cpp
Hello.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Hello.cpp:3:9: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
  int int=0;
         ^
Hello.cpp:4:14: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
  printf("%d",int);
```

Should not `keywords` be *denied assignment of values* in Python, like in C++?

Comment: why do you think that print is a keyword? https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keywords-identifier

why not try your test with an actual keyword and then see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

**Because Python is not C++.**

- From that you have some pros and some cons - its up to you to know and understand your use-case and use the language that's appropriate in your specific case.
- No programming language will serve you as a silver bullet and solve all your problems and questions